# How to display a scientific number of any power in terms of any desired power

Tags: c++, qt

A double type variable holding the value in scientific form.Lets say

```
v=1.3657e-07
```

i want to display it in powers of -09 . In label it should look like

```
136.57
```

How can i do this? is there are any function in iomanip? or it needs to be done manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you mean*, how to multiply a number by 10<sup>9</sup> in C++, that's simply `* 1e9`.

*If you literally mean*, how to express the number in terms of powers of 9, i.e. in the base 9 system, then:

There is no direct support for general number system conversions in C++.

One simple approach is to take 9's logarithm of the number. The fractional part gives you a mantissa, and the integer part gives you an exponent. Then compute the base 9 representation of the mantissa.

The base R logarithm of a number x is ln(x)/ln(R).

To compute the first base 9 digit of a number x < 1, just multiply it by 9. Chop off that digit, store it, and repeat. Essentially the multiplication is shifting the digits sequence 1 step left.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish to display it as if the exponent were -9 instead of -7 (in which case your number would be `136.57`).

To do this, simply *multiply* by the correct power and use the desired precision:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision( 2 ) << (v * 1e9)
```

Hope this helps.